# How to add fastcgi support to nginx?

Tags: centos, nginx, fastcgi

I'm trying to setup roundcube in my server with nginx on CentOS.

[this tutorial](http://robido.com/server-admin/how-to-install-roundcube-with-nginx-postfix-and-dovecot/) says:

> Add the following to the bottom of /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params:
>
> ```
> # Roundcube config
> fastcgi_keep_conn on;
> fastcgi_split_path_info       ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
> fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
> fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED    $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
> ```

But I'm getting this error trying to restart nginx service

```
unknown directive "fastcgi_keep_conn" in /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params:26
```

I googled it and [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/226321/unknown-directive-fastcgi-pass-on-nginx) says:

> seems that nginx was built without `fastcgi` support

But I can't figure out how to make nginx supports `fastcgi`

Anyone can tell me how?

Comment: Which version of nginx are you using?

Comment: @MichaelHampton `nginx version: nginx/1.0.15`

Comment: [current stable is 1.6](http://nginx.org/en/download.html), [1.0 is very old](http://nginx.org/en/CHANGES-1.0) - keep your stack up to date =).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://nginx.org/r/fastcgi_keep_conn) states:

> This directive appeared in version 1.1.4.

With version 1.0.15, you won't be able to use it.

You can either [upgrade nginx](http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#stable), or omit the directive.

Comment: you're right. tanx. Does my old nginx configurations get affected if I upgrade the nginx?

Comment: this is the web server, it must be always up to date, backup your config dir in case